# UNNotificationAttachment video preview has wrong orientation

Tags: ios, swift, unnotificationserviceextension, unnotificationattachment

I'm attaching mp4 file, that was recorded using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`, to notification in `UNNotificationServiceExtension`

Apparently, video frames is upside down and orientation is specified in metadata

If I open video in notification it's played correctly, but preview is upside down

I've tried specify clipping rect like that

```swift
    do {
        let upsideDown = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1), size: CGSize(width: 1, height: -1))
        try bestAttemptContent.attachments = [UNNotificationAttachment(
            identifier: UUID().uuidString,
            url: localurl!,
            options: [
                UNNotificationAttachmentOptionsTypeHintKey: kUTTypeMPEG4,
                UNNotificationAttachmentOptionsThumbnailClippingRectKey: upsideDown.dictionaryRepresentation,
                UNNotificationAttachmentOptionsThumbnailTimeKey: NSNumber(5.0)
            ]
        )]
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

But this code doesn't display preview at all (however video still works correctly)